# Sorting Text Value in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a text field. The field stores data as `<60%,>90%, 60%-70%, 80%-90%`. I want to sort the data so that the result should look like : `<60%, 60%-70%, 70%-80%, 80%-90%, >90%`. How can I achieve this in postgresql?

Answer (score 1):

use `regex_replace()`

```
select * from tableA order by regexp_replace(sortdata, '\D','','')
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=6dddnpj7pn)

Comment: Wont it change `60%-70%` to `6070`? And 6070 is greater than, say, 80.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the string to an [integer range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html)

```
select *,
       case 
         when col_x like '>%' then '('||regexp_replace(col_x, '[>%]', '', 'g')||',)'
         when col_x like '<%' then '(,'||regexp_replace(col_x, '[<%]', '', 'g')||')'
         else '['||translate(col_x, '-%', ',')||')'
       end::int4range as range
from x
order by range;
```

The CASE expressions converts `<60%` to the range `(,60)` and `>90%` to the range `(90,)`

Online example: https://rextester.com/KIK90562